# How to access a checkbox in a DataList using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I have a `datalist`, and each item in the `datalist` has a `checkbox` and disabled `button`, I want when the `checkbox` is checked, the button will be enabled .

How to access the check box event for an item in the `datalist` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps given below:

1. Define OnCheckedChanged method of CheckBox at design time
2. In the OnCheckedChanged method find DataListItem
3. Find the required control in the DataList; you can find it in the current row as well using index of the current DataListItem
4. Change the enable property of the control you found

It'll look something like this:

```
    protected void CheckedChangeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox)sender);
        DataListItem item = ((DataListItem)CheckBox.NamingContainer);
        if (checkBox.Checked)
        {
            ((Button)dataList.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("btnControl")).Enabled = true;
        }
     }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does it tested ? I did exactly like this, but the control is not enabled !!

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see whether it is setting the attribute at all?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to declare a `Private WithEvents chk As CheckBox` (WithEvents will let you have a reference for the checkbox inside the datalist)

Then inside the `DataList1_ItemCreated` you should do the following:

> ```
> Private Sub DataList1_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemCreated
>     If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
>         chk = CType(e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
>         AddHandler chk.CheckedChanged, AddressOf chk_CheckedChanged
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Make the chk a reference for the checkbox inside the datalist

finally you have to handle the checkbox check/uncheck event (**P.S. it is importnant to have your checkbox that is inside the datalist to have the property AutoPostBack set to true**):

```
    Private Sub chk_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chk.CheckedChanged
    Dim cb As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim item As DataListItem = DirectCast(cb.NamingContainer, DataListItem)
    If cb.Checked Then
        DirectCast(DataList1.Items(item.ItemIndex).FindControl("Button1"), Button).Enabled = True
    Else
        DirectCast(DataList1.Items(item.ItemIndex).FindControl("Button1"), Button).Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub chk_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chk.CheckedChanged

 Dim cb As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)

Dim item As DataListItem = DirectCast(cb.NamingContainer, DataListItem)

If cb.Checked Then

   DirectCast(DataList1.Items(item.ItemIndex).FindControl("Button1"), Button).Enabled = True

 Else

 DirectCast(DataList1.Items(item.ItemIndex).FindControl("Button1"), Button).Enabled = False

  End If
End Sub
```